# changing date format from dd-mm-yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: excel, date-format, vba

In my sheet, cells has dates in dd-mm-yyyy format and I am using those date for sql query which accept date format in yyyy-mm-dd format . for that i am converting dates to yyyy-mm-dd format as follows : -

```
Dim startDate As Date, endDate As Date
startdate = Format(Sheet1.Range("b1").Value, "yyyy-mm-dd")
endDate = Format(Sheet1.Range("c1").Value, "yyyy-mm-dd")
```

but i get startdate and enddate in dd-mm-yyyy format . why ????
any suggestion ...
As i am new to vba , please ignore my silly mistakes if any .
thanks in advance ....

Answer (score 0):

You need the new representation of the dates to be sent towards your database. You error is that you are converting a DATE to a STRING format and back into a DATE type.

Try something like this:

```
Dim startDate As String, endDate As String

startdate = Format(Sheet1.Range("b1").Value, "yyyy-mm-dd")
endDate = Format(Sheet1.Range("c1").Value, "yyyy-mm-dd")
...
```

(not 100% sure that `string` is the correct keyword, but I'm sure you got the idea).